# Best method to maintain a state in JBPM 4.4

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm, jpdl

In the flow of my Jpdl file, I want to change a state (`boolean`) according to the user action in top of the floor and use it in the bottom. I have tried `contextInstance` and all but I think there should be a easy and better way.

How about change a **state** node according to a **decision**. Will it work?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Showing some code would also be beneficial.

Comment: @Gimby Its version 4.4